# Linear regression with expanding parameters

Tags: regression, online-algorithms

I am doing vanilla linear regression except for that case that the features expand over time. Let me define what I mean by expand. Imagine that there is a 'complete' set of features $F$. The features known at time $t$ are $f_t \subseteq F$. Over time $f_t$ becomes a larger subset of $f$ e.g. $f_{t} \subseteq f_{t+1} \subseteq F$.

I get examples of how $f_T$ corresponds to the dependent variable $y$ at each time step. The set of all data is $\{<y_{t=1},f_{t=1}>, <y_{t=2},f_{t=2}>, \cdots , <y_{t=T},f_{t=T}>\}$ where $T$ is the current time step.

Characteristics of the problem:

- We don't know what $F$ is. I.e. the features available may expand infinitely though. In my work I do expect the feature set to stop expanding at some point but I don't know what that point is.
- We could consider this to be the problem of learning with missing features where features are missing until we get all $F$ features. However, as we we don't necessarily know we have arrived at F, the number of missing features is unknown.

I want to do regression on-line using the specified data. This would require some how taking previous regression estimates and incorporating them into a larger feature space. If this is no feasible then performing regression using the data perceived so far is also feasible. This second case at least allows us to know how many features are missing in earlier feature sets in our data relative to our largest seen feature set.

Comment: 1. Your post isn't clear. Please describe the situation in detail aiming for clarity (especially keep in mind many readers may be used to slightly different terminology or notation, so define your data, your model and so on). Pictures may help. 2. The scope of your final sentence seems to be much too broad.

Comment: I've tried to be as clear as possible now. I think that introducing the actual problem I'm working on isn't appropriate for stats.

Comment: I think it's reasonably clear and that it's actually very doable, specifically for linear regression.  I would change your statement about the "expanding features" to $f_t \subset f_{t+1} \subset F$.

Comment: Done. I look forward to hearing how.

Comment: I have no clear idea what you intend by "This would require some how taking previous regression estimates and incorporating them into a larger feature space". Are you simply trying to update parameter estimates as predictors are added? Or are you adding new data values and new predictors at the same time? Or are you after something else?

Comment: Say we learn a weighting $w$ corresponding to the feature set $f_t$  observed at a time step $t$. However at $t+1$ this feature set might expand. We do not know how the weights $w_t$ relate to the new elements of our feature set $f_{t+1}$. This would involve adding new data values and predictors while incorporating previous estimates of $w$.

Comment: One idea could be to include the former data as prior distribitions on the coefficients ... I will try to write out an answer along such lines.